# Apache NiFi GetMongoProcessor - not continuously producing flow files

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I have managed to connect NiFi to MongoDB using GetMongo Processor. I am using query to limit amount of data returned from MongoDB, but it is still millions of records. I have executed the GetMongo Processor and I have expected that when record is read from mongo db cursor, it will be batched and eventually written to a flow file. 
This is not happening. Records are flowing from MongoDB (based on tcpdump and network traffic), but no flow file is being emitted while results are still being fetched from the cursor.

See state after 10minutes of records fetching: 
[image]

Just for test purposes, when I have set the "limit" parameter to fetch only 100 records, flow files were emitted. But I don't want just some 100 records, I want all records matching my query.

Is there any setting that I could change ?

Comment: I think `GetMongo` processor will get all the records from the DB and then processor will create batches based on the value. This processor `won't store` the state so this processor will result `all records from database`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is limiting the processor. The processor is committed to execute the query. It is not aware of any limits you put.

Instead of using a limit in your query(which limits the final result for each execution), I think that using the `Batch Size` and `Results Per FlowFile` would be more fit for you.